# HABTM CakePHP no results for related model

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have problem with HABTM models. When I try to fetch any related model f.e. like this:

```
$this->Tagi->find('first');
```

I dont get any results for associated model. Result looks like this:

```
array(
    'Tagi' => array(
        'id' => '1',
        'nazwa' => 'sth'
        ),
    'Instytucje' => array()
)
```

I am sure that there should be result, I've double checked it, even

```
$this->Tagi->getDataSource()->getLog(false, false)
```

shows correct query, that fetches right results.
If you have any idea whats wrong plz give me a hint.

**Tagi model:**

```
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Instytucje' =>
        array(
            'className' => 'Instytucje.Instytucje',
            'joinTable' => 'instytucje-tagi',
            'foreignKey' => 'tag_id',
            'associationForeignKey' => 'instytucja_id',
            'unique'=> true
        )
);
```

**Instytucje model:**

```
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Tagi' =>
        array(
            'className' => 'Instytucje.Tagi',
            'joinTable' => 'instytucje-tagi',
            'foreignKey' => 'instytucja_id',
            'associationForeignKey' => 'tag_id',
            'unique'=> true
        )
);
```

**EDIT:**
Main problem is that HABTM refers to AppModel causing error:

```
Error: Table app_models for model AppModel was not found in datasource prod.
```

Which can be bypassed by adding `$useTable` in AppModel, which results in prior problem.

**SOLVED**
When using naming convention far beyond this Cake use, you have use third model with `$useTable` pointed on reference table. 
Moreover its important to correctly point Cake to classes inside plugins.

Comment: Could you perhaps include the generated SQL so that we can see that working? Also have you checked that your models don't use an `afterFind()` callback to alter the data?

Comment: I checked generated SQL, it fetches right results:

'SELECT `Instytucje`.`id`, `Instytucje`.`nazwa`, ****, `AppModel`.`instytucja_id`, `AppModel`.`tag_id` FROM `epf`.`instytucje` AS `Instytucje` JOIN `epf`.`instytucje-tagi` AS `AppModel` ON (`AppModel`.`tag_id` = 1 AND `AppModel`.`instytucja_id` = `Instytucje`.`id`) ' **** -stands for other fields of the table (thats pretty long list).

Comment: is there a reason why your query is aliasing Tagi as `AppModel`? That looks incorrect to me and might be causing the issue.

Comment: Dunno, do You have any idea why it is doing so? Its not on purpose named AppModel.

Comment: It may alias instytucje-tagi as AppModel because I dont have model for table thats shows relation between 'Instytucje' and 'Tagi'.

Comment: That might be the case as you're not using Cake's naming conventions. Is there a reason for that as it might cause you a lot of issues?

Comment: Unfortunatelly db has to stay as it is. I can't modify it, other webpages are based on it. 

EDIT: OK it stays in result, so this may cause a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're problem relates to the fact that you are not using CakePHP's naming conventions. From the look of the query being generated Cake doesn't know how to correctly alias the join table, hence getting an `AppModel` alias in your query. I suspect that this is causing issues when Cake tries to build the results array from the query.

This might not work, but try creating a model for the joins table called `InstytucjeTagi`; then update your associations to use this using the `with` key:-

**Tagi model:**

```
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Instytucje' =>
        array(
            'className' => 'Instytucje.Instytucje',
            'joinTable' => 'instytucje-tagi',
            'with' => 'InstytucjeTagi',
            'foreignKey' => 'tag_id',
            'associationForeignKey' => 'instytucja_id',
            'unique'=> true
        )
);
```

**Instytucje model:**

```
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Tagi' =>
        array(
            'className' => 'Instytucje.Tagi',
            'joinTable' => 'instytucje-tagi',
            'with' => 'InstytucjeTagi',
            'foreignKey' => 'instytucja_id',
            'associationForeignKey' => 'tag_id',
            'unique'=> true
        )
);
```

If this doesn't fix it try using the [`afterFind()` callback](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/callback-methods.html#afterfind) in the `Tagi` model to check what Cake is returning:-

```
afterFind($results, $primary = false) {
    parent::afterFind($results, $primary);
    // Print out the $results to check what Cake is returning.
    debug($results);
    return $results;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly it doesn't work. Using model for relations table doesn't change the query. Cake still uses AppModel inside it.
Moreover afterFind callback doesn't show results from 'Instytucje' model. First all Tags, then every tag separeted and in the end tag merged with empty 'Instytucje' array.

Comment: Did you update the associations to use the new model? Could you post the results from the `afterFind()`, it might help to see what's going on.

Comment: Important info - it uses AppModel because I used $useTable in AppModel. Without it I got 
    Error: Table app_models for model AppModel was not found in datasource prod.

Comment: @Maxiz you shouldn't be setting `$useTable` in `AppModel`. This implies there is something else wrong. As you're not using standard naming conventions you probably need to use this in each model to set the relevant table. It sounds like you are using `AppModel` incorrectly as this error implies it is being accessed directly (which it shouldn't). `AppModel` is for placing common model code that wants extending by your models.

Comment: Each model has corresponding $useTable set. Until using HABTM everything works, all relation types except HABTM. Using $useTable in AppModel was trick to let me work on other parts further. Both models 'Tagi' and 'Insytytucje' are extending AppModel. Somehow HABTM refers to AppModel class, even though HABTM has defined 'with' parameter. Any idea why HABTM with not orthodox naming convention refers to AppModel?

Comment: Did you define `$useTable` for the `InstytucjeTagi` model? If not because you've defined it for `AppModel` it will use that for the joins table. You should never set `$useTable` on `AppModel` as that will stop Cake from being able to generate table names properly!

Comment: Yes, I defined `$useTable` for `InstytucjeTagi`. Still cake gives me same error about `app_models` table.

Comment: OK, everything works now. 'with' parameter helped to solve the problem, just needed correct naming, thus whole thing is inside plugin 'Instytucje' - I know very bad naming convention, but I am working on someone else part of the code. Thx for help drmonkeyninja .

Comment: @Maxiz glad to have helped. Please accept my answer as the correct one (and possibly upvote it) so that it might help anyone else who comes across this page looking for answers. :-)